# Tika language detection taking several minutes

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Tika to detect languages and it usually works and is fast enough. Sometimes, there will be a file with a bunch of numbers and whitespace that seems to throw it off and it takes several minutes to determine a language. Is there a way to have the detection model return if it hasn't figured it out in X seconds?

```
final java.util.List<com.optimaize.langdetect.profiles.LanguageProfile> languageProfiles = (java.util.List<com.optimaize.langdetect.profiles.LanguageProfile>) (Object) new LanguageProfileLoader().languages;
LanguageDetector languageDetector = LanguageDetectorBuilder.create(NgramExtractors.standard()).withProfiles(languageProfiles).build();
final TextObject textObject = textObjectFactory.forText(input);
languageDetector.getProbabilities(textObject));
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Do you have a file you can share that demonstrates the problem? If so, https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA/summary is the place to report it